NVM Configuration of readall without write operation causing integrity failure
I am facing one issue in nvm configuration. I am using vector stack. Here for some blocks readall is enabled but write all is not enabled and write_block also happens either by executing diagnostic services or else if some conditions are satisfied
Due to this iam getting integrity failure duringNvm_readall once i flash the  sw  . How can i resolve this issue
Is reading nvm block without writing it caus integrity failure?

How about registering a callback for init and/or state of each block. Then you could initialize the failing blocks with default data, and call NvM_WriteBlock() on the ones, that fail currently.
The blocks will always fail, until you have them initialized at least once, and called NvM_WriteBlock() on them to store the initial block data once.
The NvM_ReadAll() function description in the AUTOSAR_SWS_NVRAMManager.pdf chapter 8 should tell you about all the conditions.
